# Problem With Guest Additions in Ubuntu Server [Virtual Box]

Tags: server, apt, kernel, virtualbox, xorg

I have a problem installing Guest additions in ubuntu server with kernel 3.13.0-39-generic
I install whole headers for this kernel with 
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms

And when i do 
$ ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Returns this error:
"The headers for the current running kernel were not found. If the following module compilation fails then this could be the reason.
Building the main Guest additions module ...fail!
(look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong)
Warning: unknow version of the X Window System installed. Not installing X Window System drivers.

And the rest is done...
i also did
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core

I will gonna crazy i got 2 days looking for internet and trying everything but nothing works...
It was on Ubuntu Server
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the fully updated current version of Ubuntu. There is no need to separate install of any kernel headers or any other packages, up-to date current Ubuntu is absolutely enough to install VirtualBox additions (I did it few times recently).

Comment: Thanks! I tried aptitude -full update and doesn't run, just do the update still Guest Additions doesn't works... :S

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed `VirtualBox`?
On the virtualisation host you only need to install the package `virtualbox` and you should be ok.  Don't forget to check documentation in `/usr/share/doc/virtualbox`.

If you want the have the file sharing stuff in the virtual machine, just install `virtualbox-guest-utils` and have a look in `/usr/share/doc/virtualbox-guest-utils`.  If you want to use the graphical extentions, install package `virtualbox-guest-x11` and have a look in `/u/s/d/virtualbox-guest-x11` for documentation.
No need to install anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I had a Windows 10 host and running an Ubuntu 20.04 guest through the Virtualbox.
The following worked for me:
First installed the essential linux headers using:
$ sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Next browsed over to the path:
/media//VBox_GAs_x.xx.xx

and ran the following: $ sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

Restarted the VM and thats it..